# When modifying a QImage using scanLine, artifacts show up. Why?

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qt5, alpha-transparency

My application has different color modes. Therefore, I need to render my icons in different colors.

My icons are grayscale SVGs. Each color mode defines two colors for icons. One color shall replace black, the other shall replace white.

The code I use to implement this is as follows:

```cpp
struct Gradient {
    QRgb a, b;

    /// index in [0, 255]. alpha from mask modifies dest alpha.
    QRgb at(int index, int alpha) const {
        const int rindex = 255 - index;
        return qRgba(
            (qRed(a) * rindex + qRed(b) * index) / 255,
            (qGreen(a) * rindex + qGreen(b) * index) / 255,
            (qBlue(a) * rindex + qBlue(b) * index) / 255,
            (((qAlpha(a) * rindex + qAlpha(b) * index) / 255) * alpha) / 255
        );
    }
};

class Icon {
public:
    explicit Icon(const QString &path): path{path} {}

    /// must set once before rendering pixmaps.
    /// generates a mask image from the source SVG with the given size.
    void setSize(QSize size) {
        if (mask.size() != size) {
            QSvgRenderer renderer(path);
            if (renderer.isValid()) {
                mask = QImage(size, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
                mask.fill(Qt::transparent);
                QPainter svgPainter(&mask);
                renderer.render(&svgPainter);
            }
        }
    }

    /// renders a pixmap that uses primary where the mask is black,
    /// secondary where the mask is white. Mask defines transparency.
    QPixmap paint(const QColor &primary, const QColor &secondary) const {
        QImage buffer(mask.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
        Gradient gradient{primary.rgb(), secondary.rgb()};
        for (int y = 0; y < mask.height(); ++y) {
            const QRgb *srcLine = reinterpret_cast<const QRgb*>(mask.constScanLine(y));
            QRgb *destLine = reinterpret_cast<QRgb*>(buffer.scanLine(y));
            for (int x = 0; x < mask.width(); ++x) {
                const QRgb &src = srcLine[x];
                // using red as indicator for the grayscale color.
                destLine[x] = gradient.at(qRed(src), qAlpha(src));
            }
        }
        QPixmap pixmap;
        pixmap.convertFromImage(buffer);
        return pixmap;
    }

    bool isNull() const {
        return mask.isNull();
    }
private:
    QString path;
    QImage mask;
};
```

This code generates strange artifacts in the output:

[image]

From this input:

[image]

This is rendered with primary and secondary colors both `#657590`. The dark blue is the backing widget's background color. The original icon just has the cog outline.

Why are the additional rectangular parts created? They are not part of the source image. I tried to use `buffer.setPixel` instead of `scanLine`, but that produced the same output.

Comment: I gave your question about five seconds of eye time, so pardon me if I missed something. are you operating in-place? is there auto-parallelization or threading going on? what does the input (all inputs) look like? [mre] requires inputs to be given.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Added input. Skipped it originally because imgur wouldn't take an SVG, sorry about that. As shown in `paint`, I create a local buffer QImage and modify it. Only threading interference that could happen would be calling `setSize` while the image renders, but both functions are only ever called from the main thread.

Comment: ah, your "render" is so small, I had trouble recognizing much. perhaps present a larger render. -- what I see here is the svg rendering operating in "stripes", and only touching pixels in those rows of a stripe that actually intersect some SVG content. inspect the alpha channel only. what does it show?

Comment: I identified the problem being the image format `QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied`. If I use `QImage::Format_ARGB32` instead, the artifacts vanish. I used the format because Qt docs say that's what's needed for rendering to be fast. I guess I'll post this as answer later unless someone else posts an answer how to fix the code to work with the „faster“ format (or maybe that doesn't apply anyway when you modify the raw image data?)

Comment: those aren't artefacts. they aren't even visible, if you involved the alpha channel for displaying. you merely viewed the RGB data on its own. but yes, you need to know if you have straight or premultiplied alpha (great resource on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XobSAXZaKJ8), and you need to tell whatever APIs which type of data it is, if they can even handle both types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the image format `QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied`. The way I modified the image, `QImage::Format_ARGB32` was appropriate. Using that format solved the problem.